# Getting a PDO query string with bound parameters without executing it

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Is it possible to get a query string from a PDO object with bound parameters without executing it first? I have code similar to the following (where $dbc is the PDO object):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
$result = $dbc->prepare($query);
$username = 'bob';
$result->bindParam(1, $username);
echo $result->queryString;
```

Currently, this will echo out a SQL statement like: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?". However, I would like to have the bound parameter included so that it looks like: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'bob'". Is there a way to do that without executing it or replacing the question marks with the parameters through something like preg_replace?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements

Comment: For PHP >= 5.1, take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In short: no. See [Getting raw SQL query string from PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements/210693#210693)

If you want to just emulate it, try:

```
echo preg_replace('?', $username, $result->queryString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't see it in the related questions part.

Comment: The code looks wrong. `preg_replace` expects a regex pattern, which `'?'` isn't.

Answer (score 8):

This is a generic variation of the [regexp technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements/210693#210693), for a numbered array of parameters.

It was a bit more paranoid than the accepted answer because quoting *everything*, numbers included, has bitten me in the backside more than once; in MySQL as well as elsewhere<sup>1</sup>, '123' is *less* than '13'. Same goes for `'NULL'`, which is *not `NULL`*, and `'false'`, which is obviously *true*.

It has now been pointed out to me that I was not paranoid **enough** :-), and my `?` replacement technique (`"#\\?#"`) was *naïve*, because the source query might contain question marks as text in the body for whatever reason:

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT('Is ', @value, ' ', ?, '? ', 
       IF(@check != ? AND 123 > '13', 'Yes!', 'Uh, no?')) 
       ;

$values = array('correct', false, 123);

// Expecting valid SQL, selecting 'correct' if check is not false for 123
// and answering Yes if @check is true.
```

Output:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Is ', @value, ' ', 'correct', '? ',
   IF(check != false AND 123 > '13', 'Yes!', 'Uh, no?')) 
   ;

Is THIS_TEST correct? Yes!
```

My simpler implementation would have thrown an exception seeing too many question marks. An even simpler implementation would have returned something like

```
Is THIS_TEST correcttrue Uh, no
```

So this is the amended function. **NOTE**: I know there are [things regexes shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). I do not claim this function to be working in all instances and for all border cases. I claim it is a *reasonable attempt*. Feel free to comment or email with non-working test cases.

```
function boundQuery($db, $query, $values) {
    $ret = preg_replace_callback(
        "#(\\?)(?=(?:[^']|['][^']*')*$)#ms",
        // Notice the &$values - here, we want to modify it.
        function($match) use ($db, &$values) {
            if (empty($values)) {
                throw new PDOException('not enough values for query');
            }
            $value  = array_shift($values);

            // Handle special cases: do not quote numbers, booleans, or NULL.
            if (is_null($value)) return 'NULL';
            if (true === $value) return 'true';
            if (false === $value) return 'false';
            if (is_numeric($value)) return $value;

            // Handle default case with $db charset
            return $db->quote($value);
        },
        $query
    );
    if (!empty($values)) {
        throw new PDOException('not enough placeholders for values');
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

One could also [extend PDOStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431305/extending-pdo-statement-class) in order to supply a `$stmt->boundString($values)` method.

---

(1) since this is PHP, have you ever tried `$a = 1...1; print $a;`?

Comment: I'm looking for answer like this since long time :(. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Hello from the future :)

```
$sth->debugDumpParams();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Just write this line without any wardump and you will be fine.
[image: It will save you.]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One extra bit of info is that in order to get the "Sent SQL" you need to call debugDumpParams after calling execute() on the statement.