# php pdo prepare repetitive variables

Tags: php, pdo

While writing a pdo statement, is it possible to repeat the value of a variable? I mean:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET firstname = :name WHERE firstname = :name";
$stmt = $dbh -> prepare($query);
$stmt -> execute(array(":name" => "Jackie"));
```

Please note that I repeat the ":name" nameholder whereas I provide the value only once. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simple answer is: You can't. PDO uses an abstraction for prepared statements which has some limitations. Unfortunately this is one, you have to work-around using something like

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET firstname = :name1 WHERE firstname = :name2";
$stmt = $dbh -> prepare($query);
$stmt -> execute(array(":name1" => "Jackie", ":name2" => "Jackie"));
```

In certain cases, such as emulated prepared statements with some versions of the PDO/MySQL driver, repeated named parameters are supported; however, this shouldn't be relied upon, as it's brittle (it can make upgrades require more work, for example).

If you want to support multiple appearances of a named parameter, you can always [extend PDO and PDOStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3431305/) (by classical inheritance or by composition), or just PDOStatement and set your class as the statement class by setting the `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS` attribute. The extended PDOStatement (or `PDO::prepare`) could extract the named parameters, look for repeats and automatically generate replacements. It would also record these duplicates. The bind and execute methods, when passed a named parameter, would test whether the parameter is repeated and bind the value to each replacement parameter.

Note: the following example is untested and likely has bugs (some related to statement parsing are noted in code comments).

```
class PDO_multiNamed extends PDO {
    function prepare($stmt) {
        $params = array_count_values($this->_extractNamedParams());
        # get just named parameters that are repeated
        $repeated = array_filter($params, function ($count) { return $count > 1; });
        # start suffixes at 0
        $suffixes = array_map(function ($x) {return 0;}, $repeated);
        /* Replace repeated named parameters. Doesn't properly parse statement,
         * so may replacement portions of the string that it shouldn't. Proper
         * implementation left as an exercise for the reader.
         *
         * $param only contains identifier characters, so no need to escape it
         */
        $stmt = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?:' . implode('|', array_keys($repeated)) . ')(?=\W)/', 
            function ($matches) use (&$suffixes) {
                return $matches[0] . '_' . $suffixes[$matches[0]]++;
            }, $stmt);
        $this->prepare($stmt, 
                       array(
                           PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('PDOStatement_multiNamed', array($repeated)))
            );
    }

    protected function _extractNamedParams() {
        /* Not actually sufficient to parse named parameters, but it's a start.
         * Proper implementation left as an exercise.
         */
        preg_match_all('/:\w+/', $stmt, $params);
        return $params[0];
    }
}

class PDOStatement_multiNamed extends PDOStatement {
    protected $_namedRepeats;

    function __construct($repeated) {
        # PDOStatement::__construct doesn't like to be called.
        //parent::__construct();
        $this->_namedRepeats = $repeated;
    }

    /* 0 may not be an appropriate default for $length, but an examination of
     * ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c suggests it should work. Alternatively, leave off the
     * last two arguments and rely on PHP's implicit variadic function feature.
     */
    function bindParam($param, &$var, $data_type=PDO::PARAM_STR, $length=0, $driver_options=array()) {
        return $this->_bind(__FUNCTION__, $param, func_get_args());
    }

    function bindValue($param, $var, $data_type=PDO::PARAM_STR) {
        return $this->_bind(__FUNCTION__, $param, func_get_args());
    }

    function execute($input_parameters=NULL) {
        if ($input_parameters) {
            $params = array();
            # could be replaced by array_map_concat, if it existed
            foreach ($input_parameters as $name => $val) {
                if (isset($this->_namedRepeats[$param])) {
                    for ($i=0; $i < $this->_namedRepeats[$param], ++$i) {
                        $params["{$name}_{$i}"] = $val;
                    }
                } else {
                    $params[$name] = $val;
                }
            }
            return parent::execute($params);
        } else {
            return parent::execute();
        }
    }

    protected function _bind($method, $param, $args) {
        if (isset($this->_namedRepeats[$param])) {
            $result = TRUE;
            for ($i=0; $i < $this->_namedRepeats[$param], ++$i) {
                $args[0] = "{$param}_{$i}";
                # should this return early if the call fails?
                $result &= call_user_func_array("parent::$method", $args);
            }
            return $result;
        } else {
            return call_user_func_array("parent::$method", $args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never had any problems repeating the same list in a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement...

Comment: In fact it depends a bit on the PDO driver, you shouldn't rely on it working.

Comment: Interesting, it has always worked for me. Do you know of any documentation on that subject?

Comment: I'd have to test it again ... there are two main cases: a) databases which like named parameters (Oracle DB and others) b) databases which support only ordinal parameters (using ? as placeholder, like MySQL) ... and then with MySQL PDO uses an complete emulation of prepared statements by default ... I don't remember how these things play together in this case and don't know a good documentation. But I know there are such issues in some combinations.

Comment: If you set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to true, then MySQL supports multiple parameters of the same name (because the prepare is emulated/replaced on the PHP site)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error appeared when I switched from dblib freedts to sqlsrv PDO driver. Dblib driver handled duplicate parameters names with no errors. I have quite complicated dynamic queries with lots of unions and a lot of duplicated params so I used following helper as a workaround:

```
function prepareMsSqlQueryParams($query, $params): array
{
    $paramsCount = [];
    $newParams = [];
    $pattern = '/(:' . implode('|:', array_keys($params)) . ')/';

    $query = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($params, &$newParams, &$paramsCount) {
        $key = ltrim($matches[0], ':');
        if (isset($paramsCount[$key])) {
            $paramsCount[$key]++;
            $newParams[$key . $paramsCount[$key]] = $params[$key];
            return $matches[0] . $paramsCount[$key];
        } else {
            $newParams[$key] = $params[$key];
            $paramsCount[$key] = 0;
            return $matches[0];
        }
    }, $query);

    return [$query, $newParams];
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET firstname = :name WHERE firstname = :name";
$params = [":name" => "Jackie"];
// It will return "UPDATE users SET firstname = :name WHERE firstname = :name1"; with appropriate parameters array
list($query, $params) = prepareMsSqlQueryParams($query, $params);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(params);
```