# How to insert new data if user_id does not exist in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

I have two columns into mysql table `map` 1. First column have name `json`, second have name `user_id`
Now, I need to insert data to new row if user_id does not exist into mysql table, but if excist I need just to update `json` column where user_id = user_id ...

I try:

```
     try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO map (user_id, json)
VALUES (:2,:1)
on duplicate key update json=values(json)");


                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['mapData']);
                $STH->bindParam(':2', $user_id);
```

Some ideas? I use php pdo.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: So you would want to insert a new user right?

Comment: not user, user_id... so if exist I need just to update json column of that row where user_id = user_id... I store user_id at every table - so I know which is data...

Comment: But if the user doesnt exist you dont have a user id. I think this is your issue. Wouldnt you then want to insert a new user and grab that id?

Comment: No, I use ajax, so when user want to insert to map mysql table , then i chech if users is loggen,if yes then I store his id and his data mapData from frontend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `:` in `on duplicate key update json=values(:json)");`, so try like this:

```
     try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO map (user_id, json)
VALUES (:user_id,:json)
on duplicate key update json=values(:json)");
                $STH->bindParam(':json', $_POST['mapData']);
                $STH->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
```

Besides, your question is related to:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390093/how-can-i-use-on-duplicate-key-update-in-pdo-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at MySQLs REPLACE command.
Cite from MySQL manual:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

That could be the solution to your problem. Otherwise, make a select, if the id exists, make an update, otherwise an insert.