# paginate() function throwing exception - PDOException SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number for in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, pdo

I am using below code to fetch records from database in Laravel

```
$products = new Product();
$products = $products->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

But it's throwing exception

> PDOException SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

It's also showing below error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 'tbl_products' where
>   'tbl_products'.'deleted_at' is null and 'category_id' = 10 and `created_at`
>   between  and ?)

I tried to find a solution which is already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028706/php-pdoexception-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number) but didn't work for me.

Before executing above code I've written code in a function and I think that code is affecting.

```
$timeframe = Input::get('daterange');
$products = $products->whereBetween('created_at', $timeframe);
```

Comment: First see `dd($products);` Is it gives you results? Also, try to change variable name after `$products = new Product();`

Comment: I don't see any errors in the following statements. Have you checked whether some other line maybe throwing this error?

Comment: Where is the code that is generating the `created_at between` (`whereBetween`)?

Comment: @RossWilson Nice question, I tried to look into the code and found that I've written a function in which other query executing related to `created_at`. There is something weird because the error is pointing to another code line which I've described in the question. So editing the question and adding that code which I wrote in a function.

Comment: I think you get `NULL` for `$timeframe` Had you got `daterange` from input?? If yes, please post it here what format it gives you!

Comment: @HirenGohel Thanks for the suggestion. It may possible that $timeframe is having NULL value, let me debug my code again because only sometimes I'm getting this error not every time.

Comment: Ok, if you get result, plz post it here..what format you get!

Comment: `$timeframe` needs to be array with 2 elements as start & end date with proper mysql date format. Verify what you are getting in that variable @Onkar

Answer (score 2):

```
$products = new Product();
$products = $products->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

This does not fetch records - you are creating a new, empty product object, and then trying to query it.

To retrieve all Products and order and paginate them, try this:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```