# PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES breaks a simple command

Tags: php, mysql

I have this very simple MCVE where even **no** table/database is affected:

```
<?php
$pdoConnection = new PDO( "mysql:host=<hostname>", "<user>", "<pwd>" );
$pdoConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE );
$command = $pdoConnection->prepare("SELECT IF('1', -:foo, :foo) AS FOO");
$command->bindValue( "foo", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$command->execute();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($command->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

The result is as expected:

```
Array
(
    [FOO] => -1
)
```

Disabling the prepare emulation with
`$pdoConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE );`

breaks totally the code. No error and also no output as nothing has been executed even it is a regular and correct MySQL code.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a *legal* reason why there is no result, or
2. is it a bug, but what causes the bug? PHP or MySQL?

**Versions:**

- OS: SLES 12.3
- PHP: 7.2.9
- MySQL 8.0.12

Comment: Specially: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028706/php-pdoexception-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number

Comment: You can't bind the same parameter `:foo` twice without emulated prepares.

Comment: @AlBundy I haven't block the question. When you use a different error reporting as described in the first duplicate you will get the error message "Invalid parameter number", which is described in the second duplicate.