# How to login with both a name/email and a password/lastname

Tags: php, html

I am trying to have my login page let users login using either their firstname/email or password/lastname.

So far, it will only allow users to login using email/firstname in the first block & in the second block only password, but not lastname.?

here is what i have so far as php-->

```
        <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
define("_APP_RUN", true);
require '../AppINIT.php';
$footerTxt = appconfig('footerTxt');
$theme=  appconfig('theme');

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
$username=_post('username');
$password=_post('password');
$login_type=_post('login_type');

if($username==''){
    conf('login.php','e','Please Enter Your Username');
}

if($password==''){
    conf('login.php','e','Please Enter Your Password');
}

   $password = md5($secret . $password);

    $lastlogin=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");





//added name,lname on 4-30-2016--to be able to login with name
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`, `email`, `name`, `lname`, `password`
                        FROM `accounts`
                        WHERE 
                            (
                                `email` = :email AND `password` = :password
                            )
                        OR
                            (
                                `name` = :first_name AND `lname` = :last_name
                            )
                        AND `status` = 'Active'
                        ");

    $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$username; ':password'=>$password; ':first_name'=>$username; ':last_name'=>$password));


//$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    //$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == "1") {
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $cmd=$value['id'];
            $_SESSION['cid'] = $value['id'];
            $lid = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
            $_SESSION['lid'] = $lid;
            setcookie("_lid", "$lid", time() + 86400);
            $login=ORM::for_table('accounts')->find_one($cmd);
             $login->online='1';
             $login->lastlogin=$lastlogin;
             $login->save();

            conf('index.php');

        }
    } else {
        conf('login.php', 'e', 'For Security Reasons We Can Not Tell You What Was Entered Wrong!');
    }

}
require ("views/$theme/login.tpl.php");

?>
```

and here is what i have in html for calling it--->

```
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
                                   <fieldset>
                                      <label>
                                         <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Email Or First Name" name="username"/>
                                            <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                                         </span>
                                      </label>

                                      <label>
                                         <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                            <input type="password" class="span12" placeholder="<?php echo $Lan['Password']; ?> Or Last Name" name="password" />
                                            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                                         </span>
                                      </label>

                                      <div class="space"></div>

                                   <div class="clearfix">
```

Read Me First!

```
                                  <button  class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-small btn-primary" type="submit" name="login">
                                            <i class="icon-key"></i>
                                             <?php echo $Lan['login']; ?>
                                         </button>
                                      </div>
```

Comment: Group the `or` parts. `WHERE (email = :user_id OR name = :user_id) AND (password = :password OR lname = :password)`

Comment: Why would you let someone login with firstname/lastname that's very unsecure. Besides there is a fair chance firstname and lastname of users are exactly the same.!

Comment: it is, but it is secured with both https and a password prompt that has hashed password that changes every day,on our servers

Comment: @Greg So every user has to login in with the password which changes every day? That doesn't make it secure. I'm talking about easy impersonation here.

Comment: @Daan   yes , the prompt box changes every day, as of right now, but i plan on changing this, within the next few weeks.

Comment: @chris85  i tried the grouping but that did not seem to work. thanks

Comment: You also can't bind the same name twice, give each binding its own name.

Comment: @chris85 can you give a example..thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603896/php-pdo-prepare-repetitive-variables

Comment: @chris85  thanks i read through it...

Comment: `bindParam - Binds a parameter to the specified variable name`, binds 1 variable, not multiples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg,

Use the following HTML Form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                    <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Email Or First Name" name="username"/>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label>
                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                    <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Password or Last Name" name="password"/>
                </span>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="Login">
    </form>
```

Use this in your login.php file:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require "path/to/db/file.php";

        $username   =   $_POST['username'];
        $last_name  =   $_POST['password'];
        $password   =   $_POST['password'];

        $password = md5($secret . $password);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`, `email`, `name`, `lname`, `password`
                            FROM `accounts`
                            WHERE 
                                (
                                    `email` = :email AND `password` = :password
                                )
                            OR
                                (
                                    `name` = :first_name AND `lname` = :last_name
                                )
                            AND `status` = 'Active'
                            ");

        $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$username; ':password'=>$password; ':first_name'=>$username; ':last_name'=>$last_name));

        $records_count  =   $stmt->rowCount();

        if($records_count   == 1){
            //One of the conditions of the $stmt was evaluated as TRUE and query was successful

            echo 'Logged in';

        }
        else{

            var_dump($stmt);

        }
    ?>
```

If the conditions are met, you should log in successfully. Otherwise, the `$stmt` will be "dumped" which will help you evaluate your input.

In your original code, you are hashing the password field. The last name is being hashed and that is why the authentication fails when you use last name.

This would solve the issue you have, but pay attention to the comments on your question. This is not a very safe way to log in. Any one that knows the first and last name of a user can log in which kind of negates the whole purpose of a log in script.

Comment: I tried your code, but it is still not taking the ( lname ) in the password block.. can you explain a little bit more on what you are wanting for me to try/do with the different user_ids and password_ids ? thanks

Comment: @Greg, why do you need this : `placeholder="<?php echo $Lan['Password']; ?>`

Comment: it echos from my lang. coding, it just outputs ( enter password ) to the front facing web

Comment: ok. I would execute the statement like this: `$stmt->execute(array(':user_id_1'=>$user_id; ':user_id_2'=>$user_id; ':password_1'=>$password; ':password_2'=>$password_2));`

Comment: check if the password is actually posted to the form action php file.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will implement this into my coding and will let you know what happens. thanks

Comment: I am verifying it this way: first check if it is username AND password and that both are correct, then check if it is lastname AND email and that both are correct.

Comment: it works great with  ( email and name with password ) but does not work at all with ( name  | lname )

Comment: Greg. Let me get this right: Log in with name and password OR last name and email

Comment: it would be this way.... login with ( name  and lname )  and also login with... ( email and password )

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check the statement in the answer.

Comment: ok .... still some problems .... i will update above in my question on what i have done...

Comment: @Greg: I will update the answer. Check it in 5 mins.

Comment: @Greg: Check the updated code for your HTML form and PHP Login page

Comment: I will update my code with your coding and , will let you know... thanks.

Comment: so i take i can comment out this--->     //$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        //$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);

Comment: @Greg: Yes. Some people would recommend that you use bindParam(). The way I execute pdo queries is by using execute() with an array. It works for me and I know how to use it so I write code that way :)

Comment: i am facing a white page , i will update code above in my question.thanks

Comment: @Greg: You are using md5 to hash the password field. It will not work with last name because it is being hashed.

Comment: @Greg: My pleasure, glad I could help. And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: i implemented your code, i faced a white screen again... but is there anyway to keep the hash on the password portion and not have a hash on using the last_name? thanks

Comment: @Greg: Look at the top part of the code. I have added a new variable `$last_name`, that is the password field without hashing then I call the hashing function.

Comment: ok... that makes more sense..., thanks... i just got to fix my white screen error and we should be good.. thanks again...

Comment: Thank you very much! once again.. i now have it fully working with no issues..Thanks to your help and re-coding.