# How to have more than one search criteria in a SELECT FROM PDO Prepared Statement for a search box?

Tags: php, select, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a prepare statement that finds the search criteria against my database which has an Articles table and Text and Title columns inside of it.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE text OR title LIKE :search');
```

My problem is that the statement only searches by title and completely ignores text.

I tried it like so and it works but I also need title

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE text LIKE :search');
```

Comment: `WHERE text LIKE :search1 OR title LIKE :search2`

Comment: To search the **same** term in both columns: `.. WHERE text LIKE :search OR title like :search`

Comment: @FirstOne If I remember correctly you cannot use the same name i.e. `:search`  twice

Comment: @FirstOne These worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: @RiggsFolly It worked for me, the :search is just what my text box is called

Comment: @RiggsFolly you can ;) You just bind once to that 'placeholder' and it will be 'assigned' to each occurrence of it in the query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you can sometimes* (?) [php pdo prepare repetitive variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603896/php-pdo-prepare-repetitive-variables). My previous comment was based on a local test - as I've used it before. But then I decided to search related posts about it and found the linked question. And from [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php): _You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on._

Comment: @FirstOne Ahh thats it. I never use _emulation mode_ but at least now I know why I thought it was not possible. ___Thanks for the clarification___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same placeholder as many times as you want *. You just have to use proper SQL syntax. See below:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE text LIKE :search OR title LIKE :search');
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And then just bind once to it:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':search', $searchTerm); // replace $searchTerm with your variable name
```

The value will fill both places.

I assume you're already adding `%` to the variable you're binding.

---

* From [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

So, as long as emulation mode is on, you're good to go. Otherwise, you'd have to name and bind them separatelly:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE text LIKE :search1 OR title LIKE :search2');
$stmt->bindValue(':search1', $searchTerm);
$stmt->bindValue(':search2', $searchTerm);
```

Comment: its pretty much exactly how I did it, thanks again

`$stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $search1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @MarisTinyD Are you sure about `PDO::PARAM_INT`? Search terms are generally strings.

Comment: PARAM_INT won't harm in practice but surely it would be sensible to change it for STR or even omit at all