# SQL Server COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
    $d              = new DateTime();
    $now            = $d->format('m/d/Y h:i:s'); 
    $pdo            = self::PdoConnect();
    $sikka_id       = $payload->office_id;
    $practice_id    = $payload->practice_id; 
    $error          = $payload->curl_result;    

    $sql = "IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [sikka_practice_utility_details] WHERE sikka_id = :sikka_id)
            UPDATE [sikka_practice_utility_details]
            SET [sikka_id] = :sikka_id
                ,[error] = :error
                ,[added] = :now
                ,[practice_id] = :practice_id
            WHERE [sikka_id] = :sikka_id
            ELSE
            INSERT INTO [sikka_practice_utility_details] ( sikka_id , error , added, practice_id )
         VALUES ( :sikka_id, :error ,:now, :practice_id )";
        
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->bindParam(':sikka_id', $sikka_id );
         $stmt->bindParam(':error', $error);
         $stmt->bindParam(':practice_id', $practice_id );
         $stmt->bindParam(':now', $now);
         $stmt->execute();
```

I've tried several variations, to no avail.

**Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
COUNT field incorrect or syntax error**

I'm learning the ways of the bindParam for PDO.

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php pdo prepare repetitive variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603896/php-pdo-prepare-repetitive-variables)

Comment: SQL Server supports `MERGE` statement.