# PDOStatement get SQL after all bindings apply

Tags: php, sql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Getting a PDO query string with bound parameters without executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530627/getting-a-pdo-query-string-with-bound-parameters-without-executing-it)
>   [PDO Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements)

Hi,
I would like to get a full query from `PDOStatement`, however I only found the `$queryString` property which seems to contain merely the original string without the bindings applied. I could iterate through the bindings and replace it myself, however I'd like to get the sql this class is working with internally. Is this possible somehow? Thanks

Comment: impossible. prepared statements are DIFFERENT from raw SQL.