# Get SQL Query and parameters from PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve (or simulate) full query from PDO prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754530/retrieve-or-simulate-full-query-from-pdo-prepared-statement)
>   [Get Last Executed Query in PHP PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716785/get-last-executed-query-in-php-pdo)
>   [PDO Debugging - View Query AFTER Bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122573/pdo-debugging-view-query-after-bind)

Using the `PDOException` class, I can get various info relating to a SQL error.  One part lacking is the actual SQL query which caused the error.  This is helpful in troubleshooting integrity constraint violation errors.  Even if the full query with inserted parameters is not available, the prepared query along with the array passed by `execute()` would suffice as I can recreate the full query.  Note that I currently do not use bindParam(), but pass all data using `execute()`.

How can I view the actual query that caused the error?  Thank you

Error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`website/accounts`, CONSTRAINT `fk_accounts_zipcodes1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`zipcodes_id`) REFERENCES `zipcodes` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)
> File Name:
>   /var/www/main/components/com_upload/models/contacts.phpLine: 520
> Time of Error: Monday October 15, 2012, 7:11:49 PDT

SQL which caused error:

> INSERT INTO accounts (id, sites_id, name, address, cities_id,
>   zipcodes_id, phone, fax, date_created, date_modified, record_status,
>   vertical_markets_id,priority_id,roles_id)
>                   VALUES (:id,123,:name,:address,:cities_id,:zipcodes_id,:phone,:fax,NOW(),NOW(),
>   "active" ,:vertical_markets_id,:priority_id,:roles_id)

Comment: Show your code and the error please

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716785/get-last-executed-query-in-php-pdo

Comment: Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786322/in-php-with-pdo-how-to-check-the-final-sql-parametrized-query

Comment: @Matt and Zlatan.  Matt's recommended thread states that it is possible by extending PDOStatement.  Zlatan's post on the other hand states that it is not possible, and one must use mysql logs as suggested by Dainis.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a zipcodes_id? It seems that would be why it would fail.

Comment: @Cfreak.  Zipcodes allowed null.  Problem was I was passing it an empty string and not null.  I figured it out, but it took adding all this test script.  I am more looking for a general strategy to trouble shoot, and not this particular problem.  Looks like either a wrapper or using the mysql logs might work, but I don't yet know for sure.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, to make sure that you get the actual query is activate the `mysql` log and see what you get as output.

On **Windows** this can be done adding two lines to your `my.ini` file:

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = "C:\path\to\log\mysql.log"
```

On **Linux** you need to modify the `my.cnf` file:

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /path/to/log/mysql.log
```

Comment: I added the following to my.cnf and restarted mysql and apache, but mysql.log still doesn't exist.  general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql.log

Comment: Dunno how it happens on `Linux`, but for my Windows machine I had to restart Windows itself. It refused to load after `apache` and `mysql` restart. + check for file/directory permission too.