# PDO bindParam error

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've written a function that should replace ?'s with values from an array, but I can't get it to work.

```
 public function exec($sql, Array $params = array()) {
            if($query = $this->db->prepare($sql)) {
                    $x = 1;
                    if(count($params)) {
                            foreach($params as $param) {
                                    $query->bindParam($x, $param);
                                    $x++;
                            }
                    }
            }
            $query->execute();
            print_r($query);
```

Query:

```
$mysql->exec("SELECT * FROM test where id = ?", array(0));
```

Output:

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM test where id = ? )
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error, but the ? isn't replaced.

Comment: `print_r($query);` will not work as the bound query does not exist in php as the query/params are sent seperately to mysql. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786322 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122573 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530627-it/530705#530705. You could use [`print_r($query->debugDumpParams());`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)

Comment: Why not skip your convoluted binding process and simply use `$query->execute($params)`?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine, the reason you still see the `?` while calling `print_r($query);` is because the values never actually gets put into the query itself.

The way prepared statements work, is that when you call `prepare()` then the query is sent to the database. Then when you later call `execute()` then all the values are sent to the database, and it will do the rest of the work.

Basically you're query and the value never ever gets connected or put together, that is also why you don't have to escape the values.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$result = $query->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

instead of

```
print_r($query);
```

Comment: Try reading the OP's questions again, since that has nothing to do with his actual problem.