# How can I display the full text of a query created by PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm creating a SQL query with PDO in PHP.  Unfortunately, there seems to be an error in my query.  I've tried `$query->errorInfo(),` but that only gives me a little bit of the error message ("There is an error in your syntax near...").

How can I display the entire query that PDO is passing to my database?

TIA.

Comment: Why don't you just post the problematic code so we can tell you what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really. This has been discussed here before, see this:

[Getting raw SQL query string from PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Thanks for showing me that - one of the comments had the answer.  Sorry - thought I had searched hard enough, guess not.  Much appreciated.