# Join two Entities in a DQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I have two entities with one-to-many relation using annotation in my DQL Query. What is the difference between those two queries?

1-

```sql
SELECT p, c FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
    JOIN p.category c
WHERE p.id = :id
```

2-

```sql
SELECT p, c FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
    JOIN AcmeStoreBundle:Category c
        ON p.categoryid = c.id
WHERE p.id = :id
```

When I check the benchmark I found the second approach take less time. Can someone list the pros and cons for each way and when each one is useful?

Comment: Can you please give the result of the benchmark? You can compare the resulting queries by [displaying them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11379563/2257664).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) you cannot execute the second query. I haven't actually tried it but you say it's possible? If so, I believe, it's bad practice to express relations in such manner...

Every `ORM` is object oriented, and such emphasizes the need for objects rather than ids. Your second query look more like a native query of relational database where `JOIN` works with ids.