# See doctrine query builder DQL with params inplace

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

Is there any chance to get DQL query from doctrine Query Builder object with all param inplace of markers?

Couse `$query->getDQL()` will return query but with params markers instead of real values, even after they have been set by `setParameter` function.

Comment: This question looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2095394/30759.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the parameters with `$query->getParameters()`

```
print_r(array(
    'dql' => $query->getDQL(),
    'parameters' => $query->getParameters(),
));
```