# Doctrine 2.5 query logging: Unknown column type "2" requested

Tags: doctrine-orm

Apologies for the long question.

I have a ZF3 based application that uses Doctrine.

I'm trying to log the "final" query that is sent to the MySQL server to the application log. For this purpose, I have implemented a solution based on [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095394/doctrine-how-to-print-out-the-real-sql-not-just-the-prepared-statement/18641582#18641582).

Note: I am aware of ZF Debug Bar, but I need to log the queries to the application log for production debugging, if needed.

However, in some situations, the logger fails with a fatal error:

```
Unknown column type "2" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

Strange part is that the error appears in the logger alone - the query executes just fine if I disable the logger.

My implementation looks like this (I use UUIDs for primary keys):

```php
'doctrine' => [
    'configuration' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'types' => [
                UuidType::NAME => UuidType::class
            ],
            'sql_logger' => DoctrineLog::class
        ]
    ],
]


class DoctrineLog extends DebugStack
{
    public function startQuery($sql, array $params = null, array $types = null) {
        parent::startQuery($sql, $params, $types);

        // If there are no parameters set, just log the query as-is
        if (empty($params)) {
            Log::debug('Executing query: ', $sql, ';');
            return;
        }

        $convertedSql = str_replace('?', '%s', $sql);
        $convertedParams = [];

        foreach ($params as $index => $param) {
            $type = Type::getType($types[$index]);
            $value = $type->convertToDatabaseValue($param, self::$dbPlatform);
            $convertedParams[] = var_export($value, true);
        }

        Log::debug('Executing query: ', sprintf($convertedSql, ...$convertedParams), ';');
    }
}
```

I investigated a bit and I have found that one particular query that fails when run through the logger is built using the `QueryBuilder`:

```php
$queryBuilder->select('m')
    ->from(Mod::class, 'm')
    ->where('m.userId = :userId')
    ->orderBy('m.dateCreated', 'desc')
    ->setParameter('userId', $userId);
```

If I create the same query using the `findBy` repository method, it logs properly:

```php
$entityManager->getRepository(Mod::class)->findBy(['userId' => $user->getId()], ['dateCreated' => 'desc']);
```

I have narrowed it down to the `$types` parameter that is passed to the `startQuery` method in my `DoctrineLog` class.

When the query logs properly (when created using the `findBy` repository method), the `$types` array looks like this:

```php
[
    0 => 'uuid'
]
```

When the query fails to log (when created using the `QueryBuilder`), the `$types` array looks like this:

```php
[
    0 => 2
]
```

I have absolutely no clue what that `2` is supposed to mean. Like I said, the strange part is that the query executes successfully, regardless of how it is created.

While for this particular query I could dump the `QueryBuilder`, this failure also happens when running a update query, so I need to either find the cause or find another way of logging the whole query.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Note: the `types` list, as returned by `\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap()` is this:

```php
[
    [array] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType
    [simple_array] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\SimpleArrayType
    [json_array] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\JsonArrayType
    [object] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ObjectType
    [boolean] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BooleanType
    [integer] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\IntegerType
    [smallint] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\SmallIntType
    [bigint] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BigIntType
    [string] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType
    [text] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType
    [datetime] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType
    [datetimetz] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeTzType
    [date] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType
    [time] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TimeType
    [decimal] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DecimalType
    [float] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\FloatType
    [binary] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BinaryType
    [blob] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BlobType
    [guid] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\GuidType
    [uuid] => Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidType
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error message. Eventually, I figured out that that the type I was passing in one of my entities for `ClassMetadataBuilder->addField( 'trace', ParameterType::STRING );` was indeed `"2"` ( the `ParameterType::STRING`). Make sure to use type from `\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types` (like `Types::uuid`) or atleast define a type your self like it states in the error.

Comment: The error present is in the logger alone and only when building the query using the query builder (see the examples). The query itself executes successfully regardless of how it is built. The `uuid` type is properly defined, as noted in the question.