# Display value of bindParam using PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Is there an easy way to echo the value stored in a bound parameter.

```
$sql ="call storedproc(:firstname, :lastname)";
$stmt = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lname);

//I want to do this
echo $stmt->firstname;
$stmt->execute;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to "see" what's going on then there's [PDOStatement->debugDumpParams()](http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.debugdumpparams):

> Dumps the informations contained by a prepared statement directly on the output. It will provide the SQL query in use, the number of parameters used (Params), the list of parameters, with their name, type (paramtype) as an integer, their key name or position, the value, and the position in the query (if this is supported by the PDO driver, otherwise, it will be -1).

Comment: It should be noted that currently this function does not print the value stored in the params without applying a patch per PHP Bug #52384 https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=52384&patch=pdo_debugDumpParams_p3.txt&revision=latest

Comment: The quote above has been updated in the php manual. The removed "the value" from it, the most important part... :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    function parms($string,$data) {
        $indexed=$data==array_values($data);
        foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
            if(is_string($v)) $v="'$v'";
            if($indexed) $string=preg_replace('/\?/',$v,$string,1);
            else $string=str_replace(":$k",$v,$string);
        }
        return $string;
    }

    $string='INSERT INTO stuff(name,value) VALUES (?,?)';
    $data=array('Fred',23);

    $string='INSERT INTO stuff(name,value) VALUES (:name,:value)';
    $data=array('name'=>'Fred','value'=>23);

    print parms($string,$data);

    $update = "update registration";
    $update .= " set status=:statusid";     
    $update .= " where refid=:refid";               
    $stmt = $db->prepare($update);

    $data=array('statusid' => $statusid,'refid' => $refid);
    echo parms($update,$data); // checking bind values
    exit; 

    $stmt->execute(array ('statusid' => $statusid,'refid' => $refid));
?>
```

//output

```
update registration set status='all' where refid='45'
```