# Why can't I bind a value to this parameter when using PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP with PDO, how to check the final SQL parametrized query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786322/in-php-with-pdo-how-to-check-the-final-sql-parametrized-query)

I am creating an in-memory SQLite database and attempting to run a query on it. I am preparing a `SELECT` statement and trying to bind a value - but it isn't working:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');

$statement = $db->query('CREATE TABLE test ( id INT )');
$statement->execute();

$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = ?');
$statement->execute(array('12'));

echo $statement->queryString;

?>
```

I expect the script to output `'SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = "12"'` but instead the script ignores the value I bound and outputs: `'SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = ?'`.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I bind a value?

Comment: You're doing it right, but going about verifying things wrong. See the dupe answer I've linked to.

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks for pointing me to that. I guess I was looking in the wrong place for the problem.