# PHP PDO Not Posting Data to Database

Tags: php, mysql, curl, pdo

I have a PHP script that is set to cURL certain URLs and then post latency & response time to a database. Yet, it doesn't post anything to the database. I've done `var_dump` on both the connection and the statement and it doesn't seem like the PDO is binding anything to the statement

```
var_dump of the statement = object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(91) "UPDATE `status` SET response_code=?, response_time=?, status=?, service=? WHERE `service`=?" } 

var_dump of the connection = object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
        require_once("config.php");

        if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
            ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        }

    function CheckURL($url, $service) {
            if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                return false;
            }

            $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GGStatus/1.0; +http://ggradio.net/)";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
                $page = curl_exec($ch);
                $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                $time = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
                curl_close($ch);

                try {
                        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `status` SET response_code=?, response_time=?, status=?, service=? WHERE `service`=?");

                        if($httpcode == 200){
                            $status = "Operational"; //green
                        } elseif ($time > 5) {
                            $status = "Delayed"; //orange-yellow
                        } else {
                            $status = "Down"; //red
                        }

                        $stmt->bindValue(1, $httpcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue(2, $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue(3, $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue(4, $service, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue(5, $service, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->execute();
                } 
                catch(PDOException $e){
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
    }

        function urlName($url){
                $name = "";

                switch($url){
                        case "http://ggradio.net/":
                            $name = "Site";break;
                        case "http://ggradio.net/community/":
                            $name = "Forums";break;
                        case "http://sv.ggradio.net:8000/":
                            $name = "Radio";break;
                        case "http://api.ggradio.net/php/song/":
                            $name = "API";break;
                        case "http://cdn.ggradio.net/":
                            $name = "CDN";break;
                        case "http://panel.ggrad.io/":
                            $name = "Panel";break;
                        default:
                            $name = "None provided";break;
                }
                return $name;
        }

        foreach($urlsToPing as $url){
                CheckURL($url, urlName($url));
        }

?>
```

Comment: var_dumping wont show you the statement after bind, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1813818/2840591

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: If I read it correct, your code only updates existing row, if any, in the database. Have you insert row for all service before running this?

Comment: @jonmrich None at all...

Comment: @KoalaYeung You're totally correct... I was under the impression that using `UPDATE` would add a new entry if one didn't already exist. Should I be using something else?

Comment: Use INSERT statement if you want a new row per-record. Or try REPLACE if you only want a row per service but nohing more.