# PDO prepared query

Tags: php, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query back from PDO prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243177/get-query-back-from-pdo-prepared-statement)

Exists any method to show, the query executed sql query in PDO Statement object?

Ex:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?";
$res=$con->prepare($sql);
$res->execute(array(1));
```

I like to view a query similar this: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1"

Comment: Are you wanting to get the query back out, or something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1`?

Comment: No i no need the query used to generate (before execute) i need the query generated (after execution) this link isn't the same that i try to ask

Answer (score 0):

`$res->queryString` should contain what you need. You can check out the documentation [here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: Really? it variable functions returns-me the same query with ?; The query before execute, I need the query after execute

Comment: I don't think PDO has a method/variable for that. Can I ask why you need this?

Comment: I have query with 6 variables (while inside while, while, while) and I will be like copy the query and try to modify manually. 
This is not important, but it simplify-me the life :p

Comment: You can generate a query log, which might help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html if you are using mysql, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123781/logging-all-queries-on-a-sql-server-2008-express-database if you are using sql server.