# get results from MSSQL prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

This code prints out a list of column names. But I would expect it to print out the information stored in the `UserName` table for the user with the `LoginName` of JSmith.

```
 $loginname = "JSmith";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserName WHERE LoginName=:login_name");
 $stmt->bindValue(":login_name", $login_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();

echo "<table><tr>";
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 print_r($result);
foreach ($result as $key => $val){
    echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";   
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Why doesn't this return the row with the users name? Looking at `echo gettype($result)` shows me that they are strings and integers; not like each piece of the returned array is itself an array. I'm sure it's a simple thing, but any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the keys, not the values. The keys are the column names, and the values are the corresponding column values.

`print_r($result)` shows that `$stmt->fetch()` returns an array with the information you expect, and the corresponding HTML simply doesn't reflect that.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#example-1018

Let's fix it.

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
foreach ($result as $key => $val){
    echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
    echo "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. However something still isn't right though. Because when I print `$val` I get the values from the first row of records. Not the record with user JSmith. Which is why I thought there was something wrong with loop. But it must be with the query. Is there some way to print out the query I've prepared so I can see if its syntax has been interpreted properly?

Comment: The query looks fine to me. You can run a similar query in your database shell to see what's actually in there: `SELECT * FROM UserName WHERE LoginName = 'JSmith'`.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2243512/1252748 recommends `echo $stmt->queryString` to see the query that was actually made. However it shows me `SELECT * FROM UserName WHERE LoginName=:login_name`. Even though I've placed it after the bindValue() line. Should I expect to see it like this, or should I expect to see it with the bound value JSmith?

Comment: You should expect to see it as you do. The parameter substitution is done by the database itself - that's the whole point of a prepared statement API such as PDO.

Comment: yeah, it must be a problem with the query though; inputting it manually retrieves the correct row.

Comment: I just noticed: you're mixing `$loginname` and `$login_name`. Assuming your real code does that too, there's your problem.