# How can I view a prepared PDO SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDO Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements)

I'm sure the answer to this is very simple, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

I'm using PDO (PHP Data Objects) to run a query against a MySQL database, and would find it useful to display the prepared query before it is executed against the DB.

Is there any way of doing this? For example:

```
$query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Comment FROM Users WHERE Id = :id';
$pdoStatement = $db->prepare($query);
$pdoStatement->bindValue(':id', $id);

// How can I view the actual statement that will be executed, showing the real
// value that will be used in place of ':id'

$pdoStatement->execute();
```

Comment: It is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411182/how-to-debug-pdo-database-queries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961897/php-pdo-how-can-i-display-the-query-pdo-just-prepared

Comment: I obviously didn't search too well, given the speed at which you both found the other posts.

Comment: @Bryan It was the first one in the related questions panel on the right hand side!

Comment: @lonesomeday I performed a few searches on Google, which didn't yield anything useful, then just posted the question without checking the related questions. My bad. Thanks again though.

Comment: debugDumpParams is the answer to this i guess

Comment: Thanks @vishal, wasn't aware of that, seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the query which is sent to server because PDO doesn't work this way.

It sends the $query seperately and $id seperately to the server-database which are executed after joining by database.

Answer (score 3):

A frequent practice is to print the query (which has placeholders in it) alongside the bound values. When using an array of the style `:placeholder => value` you can just `var_dump`, `print_r` or `var_export` the array.

This is done in Magento SQL debugging for example.

The "final" query doesn't exist as a string unless the PDO driver doesn't support prepared statements and it's simulating them.

In essence you can think of prepared statements as if they were a stored function or a stored procedure. You create it once and execute it multiple times with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 3):

use it:

```
/**
 * Replaces any parameter placeholders in a query with the value of that
 * parameter. Useful for debugging. Assumes anonymous parameters from 
 * $params are are in the same order as specified in $query
 *
 * @param string $query The sql query with parameter placeholders
 * @param array $params The array of substitution parameters
 * @return string The interpolated query
 */
public static function interpolateQuery($query, $params) {
    $keys = array();

    # build a regular expression for each parameter
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($key)) {
            $keys[] = '/:'.$key.'/';
        } else {
            $keys[] = '/[?]/';
        }
    }

    $query = preg_replace($keys, $params, $query, 1, $count);

    #trigger_error('replaced '.$count.' keys');

    return $query;
}
```

source: [View and debug prepared PDO query without looking at MySQL logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961897/php-pdo-how-can-i-display-the-query-pdo-just-prepared)