# Magento collection - filter by several fields

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, php-5.3

Using Magentos collection models, how should I go about adding a query part/filter such as this:

```
WHERE (main_table.x < 1 OR (main_table.x - main_table.y) >= 5)
```

**Update**
I'm now running this:

```
$this->getSelect()
    ->where('main_table.x < 1')
    ->orWhere('(main_table.x - main_table.y) >= :qty');
$this->addBindParam(':qty', $qty);
```

Result:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ... AND ... AND (main_table.x < 1) OR ((main_table.x - main_table.y) >= :qty) ORDER BY ...
```

The issue is that I can't seem to get to bind `$qty` to `:qty`

**Update 2**
I ended up with this, since I needed the `OR` within parentheses

```
$this->getSelect()->where('(main_table.x < 1 OR (main_table.x - main_table.y) >= ?)', $qty);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the `getSelect` method you're by-passing Magento's model collection interface.  Sometimes this is the only way to get the exact select query you want, but keep in mind it may not gel 100% with what the Magento model interface is doing.

When you use the `bindParamater` method you're using the Magento model interface.  I can't speak to **why** it's not working, but I suspect the Zend select object and the Magento model collection objects bind their paramaters at different times, and in a different way.

To get the results you want, skip the `bindParamater` method and use the simpler `?` parameter replacement of the `orWhere` method.

```
$this->getSelect()
    ->where('main_table.x < 1')
    ->orWhere('(main_table.x - main_table.y) >= ?',$qty);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Blockquote The issue is that I can't seem to get to bind $qty to :qty

Well it's actually not an issue it's the way PDO/MySQL engine is working with query statement preparation and binding parameters - which are submitted separately - and query execution afterwards.

So it's not on the DB abstraction layer to generate the final query statement if you're using *Bind Parameters*

See this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/pdo-prepared-statements/210693#210693) and [PDO manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php).

Comment: So you're saying it does work, I'm just printing the query before it's executed, and thus get misleading results?

Comment: Yes, you won't see the query string with interpolated binding which of course may irritate. For double checking, reduce your collection query by a sku or product ID with binding param.