# PDO LIKE query not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

Well, I've been at this for a few hours, and for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong.  The code is as follows:

```
$str = "%" . $_POST['str'] . "%";
$offset = (int) $_POST['offset'];

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE :col LIKE :str ORDER BY :sort LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset");
    $stmt->bindParam(":col",$_POST['col']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":str",$str);
    $stmt->bindParam(":offset",$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":sort",$_POST['sort']);

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "MySQL error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

The connection to the database works fine, no errors occur.  If I type in `%` into the search field(which would be output as `%%%` in the query), results return as expected.

I've attempted the same query in phpMyAdmin and it works fine.  I've been updating this script from the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, which worked fine before.

Example of the previous, deprecated query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE " . $col . " LIKE '%" . $str . "%' ORDER BY " . $sort . " LIMIT 10 OFFSET " . $offset;
```

As I may have already stated, I've been searching on this site as well, trying to find a solution; nothing has worked, not even MySQL's `CONCAT('%',:str,'%')`.

The server I'm testing this on is running off of php version 5.3.17.

My question, in case I did not make it clear, is what am I doing wrong here?  For those wondering(I thought that I put this but apparently I did not), there are no error messages.

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: If you're not getting an error message I'm assuming it's not throwing any error, so it's actually making the query, which in return does not return/output anything. Did you try the `PDO::PARAM_STR` in the third parameter in the `bindParam()` method for `:str` yet?

Comment: @inhan I have indeed, no change.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1376838/913097) to debug/see your query.

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying this as much as possible to make sure it really is the LIKE that's breaking (remove all the other params).

Comment: @therefromhere I removed everything after `:str`, and still no change.  @phil, #1: What would you suggest I do then to correctly sort?  #2: just below the query, using while loop to iterate through `$stmt->fetch()`: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { etc }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot use parameters in place of [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html). This means you cannot parameterise column or table names.

What your query essentially looks like when it is executed is

```
SELECT * FROM Spells WHERE 'some_column_name' LIKE '%something%'...
```

I would establish a whitelist of search and sort column names and use those to construct your query. Here's a very simple example

```
$search = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
$defaultSearch = 'col1';

$sort = array('col1', 'col2');
$defaultSort = 'col1';

$col = in_array($_POST['col'], $search) ? $_POST['col'] : $defaultSearch;
$sort = in_array($_POST['sort'], $sort) ? $_POST['sort'] : $defaultSort;

$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM Spell WHERE %s LIKE :str ORDER BY %s LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset',
    $col, $sort);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
// bind :str and :offset, and so on
```

Comment: Note that if you wanted to generate a column whitelist dynamically you could use the `information_schema` database (assuming MySql)

Comment: @therefromhere sure, but that would only be if you wanted to search / sort by any and all columns