# MySQL returns NULL even if there are records in database satisfying the conditions of SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, coordinates, great-circle

My database has entries for coordinates. I want to fetch entries containing coordinates which are in a circle of specified radius. Thus, I use [spherical law of cosines](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html).
But checking for such condition on all the database entries is too much costly.
Thus, I first get coordinates which are in a bounding box(this box encompasses the circle specified above) and then apply a `spherical law of cosines` on them.

But the problem is that MySQL returns NULL even if I have entries satisfying the conditions.
I checked above 2 conditions separately and came to know that `spherical law of cosines` works, but problem is there when use other condition(bounding box).

This [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html) has code which I use for both conditions.

Below is my code :

```
        $R = 3959;  // earth's mean radius in mile

        // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
        $from_Lat = $userTrip->fromLat;  // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
        $from_Lon = $userTrip->fromLon;  // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
        $from_Rad = $userTripLength * 0.25;  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

        $from_MaxLat = $from_Lat + rad2deg($from_Rad/$R);
        $from_MinLat = $from_Lat - rad2deg($from_Rad/$R);
        // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
        $from_MaxLon = $from_Lon + rad2deg($from_Rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($from_Lat)));
        $from_MinLon = $from_Lon - rad2deg($from_Rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($from_Lat)));


        $to_Lat = $userTrip->toLat;  // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
        $to_Lon = $userTrip->toLon;  // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
        $to_Rad = $userTripLength * 0.50;  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

        $to_MaxLat = $to_Lat + rad2deg($to_Rad/$R);
        $to_MinLat = $to_Lat - rad2deg($to_Rad/$R);
        // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
        $to_MaxLon = $to_Lon + rad2deg($to_Rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($to_Lat)));
        $to_MinLon = $to_Lon - rad2deg($to_Rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($to_Lat)));


        $sql = "Select userTrip.id, userTrip.fromLat, userTrip.fromLon, userTrip.toLat, userTrip.toLon,
        acos(sin(:from_lat)*sin(radians(userTrip.fromLat)) + cos(:from_lat)*cos(radians(userTrip.fromLat))*cos(radians(userTrip.fromLon) - :from_lon)) * :R AS SourceDistance,
        acos(sin(:to_lat)*sin(radians(userTrip.toLat)) + cos(:to_lat)*cos(radians(userTrip.toLat))*cos(radians(userTrip.toLon) - :to_lon)) * :R AS DestinationDistance
        From (
            Select userTrip.id, userTrip.fromLat, userTrip.fromLon, userTrip.toLat, userTrip.toLon,
                From userTrip
                    Where userTrip.userId != $this->userId
                    AND userTrip.departureTime > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'
                    AND userTrip.fromLat Between :from_minLat And :from_maxLat
                    AND userTrip.fromLon Between :from_minLon And :from_maxLon
                    AND userTrip.toLat Between :to_minLat And :to_maxLat
                    AND userTrip.toLon Between :to_minLon And :to_maxLon
            )
          Where acos(sin(:from_lat)*sin(radians(userTrip.fromLat)) + cos(:from_lat)*cos(radians(userTrip.fromLat))*cos(radians(userTrip.fromLon) - :from_lon)) * :R < :from_rad
          AND acos(sin(:to_lat)*sin(radians(userTrip.toLat)) + cos(:to_lat)*cos(radians(userTrip.toLat))*cos(radians(userTrip.toLon) - :to_lon)) * :R < :to_rad";

        $params = array(
        'from_lat'    => $from_Lat, 
        'from_lon'    => $from_Lon,
        'from_minLat' => $from_MinLat, 
        'from_minLon' => $from_MinLon, 
        'from_maxLat' => $from_MaxLat, 
        'from_maxLon' => $from_MaxLon, 
        'from_rad'    => $from_Rad,
        'to_lat'    => $to_Lat, 
        'to_lon'    => $to_Lon, 
        'to_minLat' => $to_MinLat, 
        'to_minLon' => $to_MinLon, 
        'to_maxLat' => $to_MaxLat, 
        'to_maxLon' => $to_MaxLon, 
        'to_rad'    => $to_Rad,
        'R'      => $R
      );

       $stmt = $this->dbLink->prepare($sql);
       try
        {
            $stmt->execute($params);
            $matchCandidates = $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
        catch (PDOException $err)
        {
            echo $err->getMessage();
        }

        if ($matchCandidates == null)
            throw new ErrorException("No match candidates found!");
```

This always shows error "No match candidates found!".
In $params array initially I used to convert latitude and longitudes into radian (even that did not work), but After debugging a lot I believe they should be in degrees.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to echo `$matchCandidates`somewhere to see if it actually contains something?

Comment: SELECT, AND, WHERE should be uppercase for good practice

Comment: @auicsc That's his problem, it doesn't contain anything, but he thinks it should. The `if ($matchCandidates == null)` code is being triggered.

Comment: Can you post some sample data to sqlfiddle?

Comment: You might be running into [some](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43203) [known](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48855) [bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64132) when trying to use float values as bound parameters in PDO.

Comment: @auicsc It does not show anything after query execution. Not even "Hello".

Comment: @Jon I echo bound parameters. They all are correct.

Comment: @AkashPatel yes, before being bound, but with how PDO works you [can't really check them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements/210693#210693) after they are bound within the query to execute.

Comment: @Barmar I cannot run this to sqlfiddle as I use variables in this query.

Comment: Replace the variables with the values you're using in the application.

Comment: you can change
`Where acos(sin(:from_lat)*sin(radians(userTrip.fromLat)) + cos(:from_lat)*cos(radians(userTrip.fromLat))*cos(radians(userTrip.fromLon) - :from_lon)) * :R < :from_rad
          AND acos(sin(:to_lat)*sin(radians(userTrip.toLat)) + cos(:to_lat)*cos(radians(userTrip.toLat))*cos(radians(userTrip.toLon) - :to_lon)) * :R < :to_rad"; `
with this `where SourceDistance < :from_rad AND DestiantiobDistance < :to_rad`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. sqlfiddle helped me.

Comment: @Amir I dont have source and destination distance until execution of this query. By using `acos` forlmula I calculate these distances.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myUserId = $this->userId

Select ...
Where userTrip.userId != $myUserId
```

You have `$this->userId` directly in the query without escaping it.

Comment: seems `$this->userId` loose its value in `select` statement

Comment: Ahh, I see it in there unescaped and such.  But really, you should never do `$this = $this->anyThing`.  Always assign to a variable other than `$this` ^^  Don't know who downvoted you, but it might help, so I'll upvote it. =] (But I'm going to edit your answer so you don't assign to `$this` ^^)

Comment: No problem, sorry for adding the explanation as well if you don't want it - wouldn't let me make the edit without changing more characters so I thought I'd add to it with something useful. ^^

Comment: @Amir `userID` have its correct value. then only I can run query when I just use `spherical law of cosines`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug and below is the right query.

```
$sql = "Select id,fromLat,fromLon,toLat,toLon,
    acos(sin(:from_lat)*sin(radians(fromLat)) + cos(:from_lat)*cos(radians(fromLat))*cos(radians(fromLon) - :from_lon)) * :R AS SourceDistance,
    acos(sin(:to_lat)*sin(radians(toLat)) + cos(:to_lat)*cos(radians(toLat))*cos(radians(toLon) - :to_lon)) * :R AS DestinationDistance
    From (
        Select userTrip.id, userTrip.fromLat, userTrip.fromLon, userTrip.toLat, userTrip.toLon,
            From userTrip
                Where userTrip.userId != $this->userId
                AND userTrip.departureTime > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'
                AND userTrip.fromLat Between :from_minLat And :from_maxLat
                AND userTrip.fromLon Between :from_minLon And :from_maxLon
                AND userTrip.toLat Between :to_minLat And :to_maxLat
                AND userTrip.toLon Between :to_minLon And :to_maxLon
        ) AS InitialResult
      Where acos(sin(:from_lat)*sin(radians(fromLat)) + cos(:from_lat)*cos(radians(fromLat))*cos(radians(fromLon) - :from_lon)) * :R < :from_rad
      AND acos(sin(:to_lat)*sin(radians(toLat)) + cos(:to_lat)*cos(radians(toLat))*cos(radians(toLon) - :to_lon)) * :R < :to_rad";
```

1) I have to give an alias to result of inner SELECT query. `Initialresult`in this case.
2) I can't use `userTrip.` in outer SELECT because it is executed upon `InitialResult`, not `userTrip`.