# return query of pdo statements

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am querying my database with pdo prepared statements and I can not figure out how to return the actual query after executing the query.
I have tried `print_r($statement);`, but all that does is give the the pdo prepared query.
Any help will be much appreciated!

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `mySite` WHERE `info` LIKE :checkSite OR `users` LIKE :checkSite");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":checkSite", "%$checkSite%");

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row['users'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite complicated task and one of drawbacks of using prepared statements.

Yet API doesn't offer such a useful feature out of the box. So, the only way to get raw SQL is to parse placeholders manually. [There are some home-brewed solutions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Ok. I am using this to create a search bar on my website...Is there a better method that will still prevent sql injection?

Comment: Err... what do you mean? Prepared statements are **the only** way to deal with SQL queries. And you can use them to create search bars as well. Why do you think you need another solution?

Comment: It just seems like to get the query information is rather strange where as querying without pdo it is easier to get the information

Comment: I have the search bar set up the issue is that I can not get the result of the query to display the proper material back to the user

Comment: You were talking of the **query**, not the **results**. What certainly cannot you get? May be you add some code to your question to make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry I miswrote I mean to get the results of the pdo query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(":checkSite", $input);
 
 $stmt->execute();

I am trying to use the results of this query to display information back to the user

Comment: Well, it makes your question totally different. Please add the code you tried to the question. Did you try  `$results = $stmt->fetchAll();` and then `foreach` them?

Comment: It displays Array
is there something wrong with my query setup?
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `mySite` WHERE `info` LIKE :checkSite OR `users` LIKE :checkSite");

Comment: Arrays intended to be **iterated**. did you try foreach? It seems your problem is basic PHP syntax, not whatever PDO issue.

Comment: $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
 foreach($results as $row){
  echo $row;
 }
is this not right?

Comment: No. $row is an array too. You need to address it's elements like `$row['users']` like every manual tell you.

Comment: nope it still doesn't display anything, wait the query is supposed to have '%stringBeingSearch%' how would I incorporate the %

Comment: add it to the bound variable, like `$stmt->bindParam(":checkSite", "%$checkSite%");`

Comment: I did that and I get this error 
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: oh, that's right. use bindValue instead. Please, read at least pdo tag wiki here first: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info I am not supposed to tell you whole PDO syntax here in the comments.

Comment: YAY it works...Is it as secure from sql injection to use bindValue instead of bindParam?