# How can I test if PDO successfully binded my variables?

Tags: php, pdo

//The variables are declared outside this function. I use `$_POST` to retrieve each user input in another .php file using html form tag.  The variable `$db` is my database connection.

function insertintodb ($db, $avar, $bvar, $cvar)
{
/*
How can I tell what values my variables are when using PDO bindParam?  I output $avar to see its value in this function.  How can I tell if PDO actually binded ":firstname" to $avar?  Likewise with the other variables.
*/

```
echo 'before <br>';
echo $avar;
echo '<br>';

    //firstname, midinitial, lastname are values in my database.
    //name is my table I am inserting into.
$insertname = "INSERT INTO name (firstname, midinitial, lastname) 
VALUES (:firstname, :midname, :lastname)";

echo 'before PDO prepare<br>';
echo $avar;
echo '<br>';

$stmt = $db->prepare($insertname);

$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $avar);
$stmt->bindParam(':midname', $bvar);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $cvar);

echo 'after binding variables using bindParam <br>';
echo $avar;
echo '<br>';

$stmt->execute();

echo 'after executing <br>';
echo $avar;
echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: define "successfully"

Comment: the mysql.log is the only place you'll find the interpolated sql queries from prepared statemants

Comment: If no exceptions were thrown, just execute the query. If the result is correct, your variables were bound correctly.

Comment: queries are prepared on DB so there is no way to see the complete SQL query.

Comment: @user2864740 yes that's what i meant. My Fault :D

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements

Comment: @user2864740 *never* scare an opening poster with such frightening words like DAL or exceptions. They want working code, not a proper one. Even if they don't know why they want it

Comment: @YourCommonSense A DAL doesn't have to be hard or complex. For a "beginner" it could be merely some functions. Exceptions are terrific and should *always* be enabled with PDO.

Comment: @user2864740 eventually you will learn that even a user-defined *function* is an impassable obstacle for an average participant under PHP tag :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Then the goal to raise the expectations :|

Comment: @user2864740 sure, it should be. But eventually you will learn what *ungrateful* a job it would be on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`bindParam()` returns `true` or `false`:

```
if($stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $avar)) {
    echo 'Woo hoo yay!';
} else {
    echo 'Boo hoo waa';
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting checking *every* bound parameter to "ensure correctness"? That is Too Much Work!

Comment: So $stmt->bindParam(':firstname',$avar) returns a bool value?  Is that for all PDO statements?

Comment: @user2864740: I am **not suggesting**, I **am answering** _"How can I test if PDO successfully binded my variables?"_  Do you have a better answer to that question?

Comment: user2864740 - I like to know everything about code.  From start to finish.

Comment: @user2864740 *Never* question a Stack Overflow participant. They *never* mind. They just answer a question.

Comment: @user3465924: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php shows parameters and return vals.

Comment: @YourCommonSense:  Thought it was obviously tongue and cheek, guess not.

Answer (score -1):

Just avoid bindParam at all. this will relieve you from burden of checking its result

```
function insertintodb ($db, $avar, $bvar, $cvar)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO name (firstname, midinitial, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $data = array_slice(func_get_args()); // lets strip $db from the func args
    $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

Comment: Seriously? I have to deal with umpteen `?`s? No thanks! That can lead to even more subtle/serious errors (i.e. on a misordering of convertible values), IMOHO. These are terrible enough when having to order columns in standard SQL :|

Comment: @user2864740 if you want to deal with twenty words instead of single character marks - it's up to you :)

Comment: I do not! That is what I am asking, how does this "relieve" a burden overall? :)

Answer (score -1):

#### *Trust PDO*

If PDO has a bug, this is not your problem. It is PDO's - since it's fairly well tested, there are very few bugs in current PDO versions. That is, if you *tell* PDO to bind, then trust that it *will* bind (PDO will fail on `execute` if there are *unbound* parameters, so we don't even have to "trust" it too much).

However, use [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) (not bindParam, except in special cases) because bindValue will ensure the *value* supplied is bound and not merely a "reference [to the variable]". This prevents "accidental changes" to variables between binding and execution from affecting the query.

#### Write and Test a DAL

*Write* a [Data-Access Layer (DAL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)<sup>1</sup>, as opposed to inline spaghetti SQL, and then *test* it. While ensuring the parameter is "actually binded" sounds useful, it isn't doesn't ensure the code is *valid semantically*. For instance, what if the code incorrectly did `$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $lastname);`?

Furthermore, PDO itself will fail (I recommend [enabling Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)) on most basic "binding failures" (such as unbound parameters or nonconvertible values) when the query is executed, making the very nature of testing if a parameter is "actually binded" less important.

Since detecting binding is *not* relevant to determining the *validity* of the code, nor can PDO report *exactly* what data is stored due SQL *conversion* issues (including truncation), then the problem really isn't about checking each bind, it's about checking operations - and a DAL provides guaranteed contracts for different operations.

---

<sup>1</sup> A DAL doesn't have to be scary, nor does it have to use "ORM" or "OOP" or "DI/IOC" or anything else (although an advanced DAL may use all of those "concepts"). Consider, for starters, a small handful of functions in a separately included file which are the *only* mechanism for connecting to the database and "talking to" SQL.

Each of these functions then has a simple contract (which as documentation on the top) which defines the parameters it takes, the results it returns, and any exceptions it may throw.

Congratulations, you've created a minimal and testable DAL!

Then this DAL, which is just a collection of functions for now, can be taken and tested/verified *outside* of the "actual program" (preferably using an existing test framework/harness).