# PDO bindParam not working in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using `PDO` for an application but getting a problem for `PDO bindParam()`. I have an array and I want to use the values of array for `PDO bindParam()` using `for` loop or `foreach()` but an unexpected result is getting by `foreach()`.  When I used `bindParam()` in `for` loop, it worked fine. What I tried was

```
$con = $this->connection();
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

for($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++){
   $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $params[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();//$result is OK
```

But when I used `bindParam()` in `foreach()` then I got an empty `array()` as result. Below the codes

```
$con = $this->connection();
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

foreach($params as $key=>$val){ //Here
    $stmt->bindParam($key + 1, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(); //$result is an empty array
```

I'm wondering why this happened. I can't find out the reason. Any information will be appreciated.

**EDIT :** I solved my problem using `bindValue()` instead.

Comment: Where is `$params` defined?

Comment: @Jez It is from function parameter!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`. `bindParam()` binds to a reference, so when you execute the query all the parameters use the last value of `$val`.

Comment: I was just about to post this. This is the correct answer.

Comment: `bindValue()` doesn't have the `driver_options` parameter. Is that necessary for your query?

Comment: @Barmar how can I show my full SQL query string before executing?

Comment: @Janie See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements

Answer (score 6):

If you already have the items in an array, there's no reason to call `$stmt->bindParam` in a loop; just do:

```
$con = $this->connection();
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> Execute the prepared statement. If the prepared statement included
>   parameter markers, you must either:
>
> call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables to the parameter
>   markers: bound variables pass their value as input and receive the
>   output value, if any, of their associated parameter markers
>
> or pass an array of input-only parameter values