# PDO bindParam not working in loop

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

I am having trouble getting bindParam to work inside of a foreach loop. If I use bindParam outside of a loop or hardcode the values into the sql query everything works perfectly. According to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164076/pdo-bindparam-not-working-in-foreach) it is suggested to use bindValue instead. However, when I use bindValue it says that the three variables used inside the bindValue are undefined. Which obviously they are at this point. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

    $found_update = false;

    $installed_groups = array(
        array(
            "group_id" => 14,
            "version" => "1.0.7"
        )
    );



    $sql = "select id from testing_set where group_id = :GROUP_ID
        and (
            substring_index(substring_index(version, '.', 2), '.', -1) > :INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_1 OR
            substring_index(substring_index(version, '.', 3), '.', -1) > :INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_2
        )
        order by created desc limit 1";

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPWD);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindParam(":GROUP_ID", $installed_group['group_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(":INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_1", $installed_version_parts[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(":INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_2", $installed_version_parts[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);

            foreach ($installed_groups as $installed_group){

                $installed_version_parts = explode('.', $installed_group['version']);

                $stmt->execute();
                $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if (!empty($data)){
                    $found_update = true;
                    break;
                }
        }

        echo "Found: $found_update\n";

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        http_response_code(404);
        die();

    }
```

My expected results are for it to display "Found: 1" to the terminal. The way it is now it has a value of false when it should be true.

**Solution:**

It turns out there were two issues going on here. I have followed IncredibleHat's answer by using basic variables rather than an array in my bindParam. This helped solve the first problem, but the other problem was that I needed to typecast some of data to an int:

```
$pt1 = (int)$installed_version_parts[1];
```

I had assumed that `PDO::PARAM_INT` was doing that for me, but it was not.

Comment: Bind actual variables.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes, but binding should be done outside of the loop whereas variables do not exist until in the loop. It's a catch 22.

Comment: That looks like it should work, if the explode results in an array with at least 3 elements, but try a temp var such as `list($z, $one, $two) = explode(.....)` and use those in bind calls.  Also `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I think you should bind in the loop and execute inside the loop. With what you have, you should be getting an undefined variable as those are only available inside the loop

Comment: The problem I've run into, is trying to bindParam (reference) to something like `$array['key']` ... it throws key undefined. And also it is an array item, not a variable. You could get away with just passing execute an array of the three items: `$stmt->execute(array($installed_group['group_id'],$installed_version_parts[1],$installed_version_parts[2]));` and do away with bindParam entirely.

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale No. He would have to use `bindValue` inside the loop (and the execute MUST be in the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to `bindParam` to an array element like `$array['key']` causes a few issues because its bound as reference, but its not. Its, just not done that way.

So three ways:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
// bind to variables that can be a reference
$stmt->bindParam(":GROUP_ID", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_1", $pt1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_2", $pt2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach ($installed_groups as $installed_group){
        $installed_version_parts = explode('.', $installed_group['version']);
        // assign the referenced vars their new value before execute
        $id = $installed_group['group_id'];
        $pt1 = $installed_version_parts[1];
        $pt2 = $installed_version_parts[2];
        $stmt->execute();
}
```

Or: (less efficient)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach ($installed_groups as $installed_group){
        $installed_version_parts = explode('.', $installed_group['version']);

        // use bindValue (not bindParam) INSIDE the loop
        // bindValue doesn't set them by reference, so any value expression works
        $stmt->bindValue(":GROUP_ID", $installed_group['group_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(":INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_1", $installed_version_parts[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(":INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_2", $installed_version_parts[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
}
```

Or:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach ($installed_groups as $installed_group){
        $installed_version_parts = explode('.', $installed_group['version']);

        // pass them on execute directly
        $stmt->execute(array(':GROUP_ID'=>$installed_group['group_id'],
                             ':INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_1'=>$installed_version_parts[1],
                             ':INSTALLED_VERSION_NUM_2'=>$installed_version_parts[2]));
}
```

Comment: Would I be correct that the second option would be less efficient because you have to re-bind each time and therefore either the 1st or 3rd option would be best?

Comment: Correct (for large operations). Its not noticed with a few queries though.

Comment: Trying out the first option it only works if I cast the the $pt1 and $pt2 to an int: `$pt1 = (int)$installed_version_parts[1];` Why is this? Should not the `PDO::PARAM_INT` be taking care of that?

Comment: You would think it would ... but its enforcing that it should be an int, instead of translating it. Heres a blurb about casting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19751442/2960971 (important to read the argument on that answer lol).