# How do I get the query builder to output its raw SQL query with inline params

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Given the following code:

```
DB::table('users')->where( 'gender' , '=', 'male', true)->toSql();
```

1. I get the raw SQL query string but it  used params.

   ```
   select * from `users` where `gender`=?
   ```

   Can I somehow inline parameters?
2. Can i say to builder to not use backquotes? now I use `DB::raw('gender')` expressions, but its not what i whant to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting raw SQL query string from PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Are you using MySQL for your database?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the getBindings() method to get the actual parameters. So something like this should work:

```
$completeSql = str_replace_array('?', $query->getBindings(), $query->toSql());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-replace-array for info on the str_replace_array() helper which works well here.

And I think DB::raw() is the way to avoid the backticks without extending stuff.

The backticks are added in the MySqlGrammar wrapValue() method. You could extend that class and then override the parts you don't like. Then you should be able to use

```
DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new YourExtendedMySqlGrammar());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions for info on raw expressions might be of use too.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf(str_replace('?', '%s',DB::table('users')->where( 'gender' , '=', 'male', true)->toSql()), 'male');
```

alternatively you could turn on query logging in your DB and look at them in there

Comment: Auch, you kidding? what if  20  params?

Comment: then use my  suggested alternative ;)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Debugbar does this for you out of the box with little to no code required. All queries and their parameters are shown in the query tab and can be copy/pasted into whatever SQL client you choose.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: I not need it for debug,  I use it in Athena  which not works  with params, only  complete  sql

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't for debug, you could use `getBindings()`.

```
$q = \DB::table('contact')->where('created_at', '2018-01-01');
$sql = $q->toSql();
$bind = $q->getBindings();
$inline = vsprintf(str_replace("?", "'%s'", $sql), $bind);
echo $inline;
```

Obviously, this only works for single valued types such as int, date, string, etc. If you have arrays, you will need to convert `$bind` so its values are only strings.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I wanted a debugging tool that could present full, easy to read, copy/pastable SQL.  At the time I was using it to expose N+1 lazy-loads that were hurting performance.  So I actually dissected DebugBar to figure out how they managed it, and came up with something that sounds like it'd suit your purposes as well.

This basically just reformats what Laravel catches in the query log.  (Of course they actually have to finish executing to be visible here.) Just make sure, if you're using any of the `raw` methods, to encapsulated field names in back-ticks, or the capitalization will look a little screwy.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
DB::flushQueryLog();

//Execute whatever code results in SQL queries

$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
DB::disableQueryLog();
DB::flushQueryLog();

$dbName = null;
$compiled = [];
foreach ($queries as $query) {
    if (DB::getDatabaseName() != $useDb) {
        $dbName = DB::getDatabaseName();
        $compiled[] = "USE `$dbName`;";
    }

    $sql = $query['query'];
    $values = $query['bindings'];

    $enclosures = [
        'back_tick' => '`',
        'apostrophe' => "'"
    ];

    $matches = [];
    foreach ($enclosures as $name => $enclosure) {
        $matches[$name] = [];
        preg_match_all("/$enclosure.*?$enclosure/", $sql, $matches[$name]);
        $matches[$name] = array_last($matches[$name]);
        $sql = preg_replace("/$enclosure.*?$enclosure/", "$enclosure?$enclosure", $sql);
    }

    $sql = strtoupper($sql);

    foreach ($enclosures as $name => $enclosure) {
        $sql = str_replace_array("$enclosure?$enclosure", $matches[$name], $sql);
    }

    $values = array_map(function ($value) {
        if (!is_numeric($value) && !is_null($value)) {
            $value = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }, $values);

    $sql = str_replace_array('?', $values, $sql);
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ';').';';

    $compiled[] = $sql;
}
```

By the way, the `DB::getQueryLog()` also includes the time it takes for a query to run, making it even more useful for diagnosing performance issues.  Just bear in mind there, connection-time is a factor.  Locally hosting your app that's remoting into a database will take longer to come back than when your project is actually live.