# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric when trying to create a record using Eloquent

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have a project that is written using `PHP` on the top of [Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/) framework. I am using [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) to interact with my SQL Server.

I am trying to user `Model::insert([  [...] ])` and `Model::create([...])` on the Eloquent model to create either a single record or bulk record.

However, I keep getting this SQL-Server error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. (SQL: insert
>   into TABLE_NAME

I understand what the issue is. But I am not sure what column is causing the problem.

Is it possible to get the raw SQL Query that Eloquent is generating so I can see what column(s) is causing the problem?

Is there a better approach to figure out the cause of this problem?

My database has 4 columns that aren't strings. So, I tried defining them in the `$casts` property on the Eloquent model like so

```
protected $casts = [
    'Bathrooms' => 'float',
    'Bedrooms' => 'float',
    'MatrixId' => 'int',
    'IntegrationId' => 'int',
    'Price' => 'float',
];
```

But still getting the same error.

I also tried to install [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) but does not log the insert query. Perhaps because of the error, the query does not get logged.

How can I figure out the problem?

Comment: If you activate the Sql profiler, then you reproduce the issue, would be easy to find the sentence sent to   sql server

Answer (score 0):

If your end goal is to get the query that is being executed, then one solution would be to find where it's writing the INSERT statement and die and dump the query it created. Since we have access to the source code we can do that.

Here is where you'll want to look:
`\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php`

In `Grammer.php` you'll find a function named `compileInsert`.

At the end it has `return "insert into $table ($columns) values $parameters";`

Tweak that to `dd("insert into $table ($columns) values $parameters");`, then write a record to the database and it should show the INSERT statement it generated.

In case it's helpful, I located the file by going to file explorer (I'm currently using Windows) and in my laravel project's directory I searched for "Eloquent". The top result was an "Eloquent" directory. I then ran quick powershell command in that directory to see where "INSERT INTO" might exist.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "insert into" | group path | select name
```

4 files were given back to me, and Grammar.php was the winner.

**EDIT:**

I realized that just gives a query with "?" placeholders for the values. Try something like this to dump the query as well as the values being inserted. Note I included an if statement to not have it accidentally fire on some other table that might get inserted before it gets to the part of the process you care about.

```
if ($table == "[your_table_name_here]") {
    dd(["insert into $table ($columns) values $parameters", $values]);
}
```

That won't give the complete raw SQL, but you should be able to get a very good idea what it ends up executing. If you do need the raw SQL it all boils down to PDO in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php`, function `statement`. And I'd point you this question for insight into that: [Getting raw SQL query string from PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements)