# See prepared TMyQuery SQL string

Tags: prepared-statement, delphi-10.2-tokyo, devart, mydac

I just want to preface this by saying I do not think it's possible, but I want to ask just to verify.

Much like with PDO, we use the TMyQuery's 'params' property to prepare SQL statements prior to execution.

**Is it possible to see the 'final' SQL string with parameter values interpolated into it?**

This is just for debugging the application, sometimes it's useful to see what the full query that is being sent to the server - especially when it's a remote server and can't check the process list.

I have a feeling that, like PDO, this data is not exposed (referencing the answer from Bill Kariwn here [Getting raw SQL query string from PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements)) just want to verify and not make any assumptions on this.

Thanks for your time!