# debug sql statements - parameter values

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql statment:

```
try {
    $sql = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO myTable (column_a) VALUES (:value_a)" );

    $sql->execute( array( 
            ":value_a"              => $value_a
    ));
        

} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

In the catch block, I get the sql error message.
But I would like to know, which paramaters and which values were send to the database.
Is there a solution for?

Comment: You can quite clearly see the parameters in the query. Debugging the values can be as simple as `var_dump($parameterArray)` or use an actual debugger to halt on exceptions

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're preparing your variables before the try-clause you can just dump them too in the catch.

```
try {
    $sql = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO myTable (column_a) VALUES (:value_a)" );
    $sql->execute( array( 
            ":value_a" => $value_a
    ));    

} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    var_dump($e->getMessage(), $value_a);
}
```

Also, if you are using PHP 5.4 or higher (higher I really hope) you could/should use short syntax for arrays. It's just nicer and easier to read.

```
$sql->execute([":value_a" => $value_a]);
```