# Python mysql paramaterised date_add query fails ('You have an error in your SQL syntax')

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-connector-python

I've got a simple SQL query that works fine from a mysql command line:

select dateandtime from times where their_id=0053 and dateandtime>= 2022-08-24 and dateandtime<=DATE_ADD("2022-08-24", INTERVAL 7 DAY);

If I try to do this programatically by doing either:

```
params = (their_id,date,date," INTERVAL 7 DAY")
query = "select dateandtime from times where their_id=%s and dateandtime>= %s and dateandtime<=DATE_ADD(%s,%s) ";
cursor.execute(query,(params))
```

or

```
params = (their_id,date,"\""+date+"\""," INTERVAL 7 DAY")
query = "select dateandtime from times where their_id=%s and dateandtime>= %s and dateandtime<=DATE_ADD(%s,%s) ";
cursor.execute(query,(params))
```

I get:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' INTERVAL 7 DAY')' at line 1

The obvious question is, is there any way to parameterise this query?
Secondly, though, to help with similar problems in future, is there any way with a parameterised query to see the query as interpreted by MYSQL once the paramaters have been parsed?

Any help would be very gratefully received!

Comment: Parameterized queries don't use string interpolation. They pass the parameter values directly to the compiled execution plan generated from a query. `INTERVAL 7 DAY` isn't a value, it's an expression that's part of the `DATE_ADD` call. Why add days in SQL anyway? You can calculate the start and end dates in python and use `datefield BETWEEN %s and %s`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thank you so much! I've sketched out an answer, but I'm not sure how the economics of stackoverflow works - I guess you get credit for an answer? Please let me know if you want to provide an answer that I can vote for, in which case I'll delete mine.

Comment: Your second question, how to get the query after parameters have been combined, is only possible in the query log. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/210693/20860 That question is about PHP, but the same answer applies regardless of language.

Answer (score 0):

As per Panagiotis Kanavos's answer above, using a query of the form:

```
select dateandtime from times where dateandtime BETWEEN %s and %s
```

... and supplying the dateandtime parameters with python datetimes, rather than strings, fixed the problem.